# Code using indirect assignment not working

Tags: c, pointers, arm

On an embedded ARM system I have implemented a register system:

- Each register is an array of uint8_T
- The host system can set either one register or more registers at the same time, by issuing a specific command on the serial port of the CPU.

This is the code, stripped down of irrelevant things. I have the problem on the multiple register write:

**registers.c**

```
#include "registers.h"

//mapped variables
uint8_t reg1[REG1_LEN] = {0x00};
uint8_t reg2[REG2_LEN] = {0x33, 0xB4 ,0xFF, 0xE0};
uint8_t reg3[REG3_LEN] = {0x11};
uint8_t reg4[REG4_LEN] = {0x00};
uint8_t reg5[REG5_LEN] = {0x06};
uint8_t reg6[REG6_LEN] = {0x00};
uint8_t reg_problem[REGPROBLEM_LEN];    
uint8_t reg8[REG8_LEN] = {0x00};


// *** quickstart register mapping.
uint8_t * const register_map_3[] = {    reg1,
                                        reg2, reg2+1, reg2+2, reg2+3,
                                        reg3,
                                        reg4,
                                        reg5,
                                        reg6,
                                        reg_problem, reg_problem+1, reg_problem+2, reg_problem+3, 
                                        reg_problem+4, reg_problem+5, reg_problem+6, reg_problem+7 //,
                                     // reg_problem+8, reg_problem+9, reg_problem+10, reg_problem+11,
                                     // reg_problem+12, reg_problem+13, pload+14, reg_problem+15
    };

  // ...

 // Array pointing to register maps
uint8_t * const * const register_maps[0x10] =
{
    register_map_0,
    register_map_1,
    0,
    register_map_3,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0   
};
```

**registers.h**

```
// Length of fields
#define REG1_LEN 1
#define REG2_LEN 4
#define REG3_LEN 1
#define REG4_LEN 1
#define REG5_LEN 1
#define REG6_LEN 1
#define REGPROBLEM_LEN 8
#define REG8_LEN 1

// number of fields
#define FIELDS                              8

//mapped variables
extern uint8_t reg1[REG1_LEN] = {0x00};
extern uint8_t reg2[REG2_LEN] = {0x33, 0xB4 ,0xFF, 0xE0};
extern uint8_t reg3[REG3_LEN] = {0x11};
extern uint8_t reg4[REG4_LEN] = {0x00};
extern uint8_t reg5[REG5_LEN] = {0x06};
extern uint8_t reg6[REG6_LEN] = {0x00};
extern uint8_t reg_problem[REGPROBLEM_LEN]; 
extern uint8_t reg8[REG8_LEN] = {0x00};

extern uint8_t * const * const register_maps[0x10];
```

**uart.c**

```
#include "registers.h"

// ...

// com_len is the number of items to copy from hexcommand
// regaddr() is a macro that gives the position in the array register_maps[]
for (uint8_t i=0; i < (com_len); i++)
{   
   *( (*register_maps[regaddr()]) + i) = hexcommand[i];                                     
}

// ...
```

uart.c is supposed to copy the content of hexcommand (coming from the serial port) and send them to the variables mapped by register_maps[n].

**EDIT:**
Having a look at the assembly output, there is something weird going on:
(*register_maps[regaddr()]) + i) <- this is supposed to give, the address of the elements reg1, reg2, reg2+1, ... as declared in register_map_3[].
What the assembly does is simply adding an increasing offset to the first address of register_map_3[]. By luck, reg1...reg6 are allocated consecutively, so it works. regproblem is located somewhere else, and that doesn't work. However, my syntax looks alright to me:

(*register_maps[regaddr()]) <- gives register_map_3

(register_map_3 + i) == ((*register_maps[regaddr()]) + i)  <- gives address of element in register_map_3

*(register_map_3 + i) ==  *((*register_maps[regaddr()]) + i)   <- gives variable (reg1, reg2, reg2+1, ...)

Am I missing something?

bonus question: is there a cleaner notation than the one I have used for register_map_3[] to "embed" an array into another one?

Comment: Wow, do us all a favor and change those variable names to something that is easy to remember by the time we reach the bottom of your question. Publish only the stuff which is relevant to the **actual** problem that you're experiencing. For example, if those UART register names are not specifically related to the problem, then use something like `R1...R16` or whatever. The title (trouble with indirect addressing) implies that all you needed to publish was a small piece of code with indirect addressing. Is all the rest really necessary here?

Comment: I'm not getting you. In the second case, 26 bytes long, didi you change the pload length to 16?

Comment: ...and did you add a comma to pload+7?

Comment: I am going to edit the question and change name to variables., thanks for the suggestion.
I thought I stripped out enough, I didn't want to lose details about how the variables were declared.
In the meantime: yes, in the second case I change the length to 16 and add a comma to pload +7.

Comment: IMHO, your code is extremely unreadable. No wonder the indirect access `*((*register_maps[regaddr()])+i)` fails at some point (assuming that this is indeed the problem). Any reason why you're not using a constant 3-dimensional array, apart from the possible memory consumption overhead? Are these memory mapped registers which must reside at specific addresses? I would expect to see a `#pragma` if that's indded the case, so I assume it is not.

Comment: In addition, I would advise to change the word `useless` to `irrelevant`. And I would also say that the word `only` is a little confusing in the context of statement "The host system can set only one register or more registers at the same time".

Comment: Yes, memory (especially RAM) consumption does matter in this case.
Some of the registers are even 255 bytes long, so I cannot waste it using maximum size for all. 
The registers are pointed by elements of structs which hold other properties, as well. This is a compromise to access those variables, keep the host cpu less busy possible, save the most RAM.

Unreadable doesn't make it necessarily wrong, do you have any guess about the malfunctioning?

Comment: Have you looked at the actual ARM assembler output here to make sure it is doing what you expect?  In embedded development with specialized compilers/libs, occasionally one can be surprised by what they see.  At the assembly level, you would also be able to check each byte written to memory and know exactly at what point the indirection is breaking down.  I have no problem reading code like this, but having a triple indirection like you have does make my head hurt a bit.

Comment: thanks @MichaelDorgan, I am trying to look into it. It looks even more obscure :)
BTW, I couldn't find any better way to do that, but that's probably my problem.

Comment: Main question was edited with details about assembler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found my own problem.
I needed to change the syntax of

```
*( (*register_maps[regaddr()]) + i) = hexcommand[i];
```

to

```
*( *(register_maps[regaddr()] + i) ) = hexcommand[i];
```

otherwise the loop keeps increasing the address of the first element of the array (reg1), instead of looking for the right address in register_map_3[]. It worked fine until, by chance, all of the addresses used in my code have been consecutive.